# How to preserve stock in a Spring Boot + MongoDB application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, java-21

I'm developing a Spring Boot 3 + MongoDB application using Java 21. My application is a sales system, and I have a concern about how to preserve and, most importantly, enforce stock integrity.

If two users try to purchase the same product of which only 1 unit is left in stock, both will see the available stock as 1, and both may proceed with the purchase. This could result in one more product being sold than there should be.

I initially thought about implementing transactionality and MongoDB locks, but these approaches failed as MongoDB doesn't provide these mechanisms.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue or what mechanisms to implement would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.
Greetings.

As I mentioned earlier, I have tried using locking mechanisms, but MongoDB does not support them.

Additionally, it's worth noting that my application is not reactive, meaning it does not implement WebFlux.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Probably you didn't choose Transaction Isolation properly, or didn't use @Transaction annotation right, provide example, pls.